# Finding out if Flash is software rendered or hardware rendered programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api, flash

I'm building a Chrome extension which work on Youtube players (@ youtube.com), I'm encountering issues when the flash player is being rendered by software and not hardware.

I know that I can find out how its being rendered by right clicking on the video and choosing "Show video info", the problem is that I need to know that at the extension level.

Is there anyway to know that using Javascript/Chrome extension options/flash api/etc... ?

Comment: I haven't done this in a while, so leaving a comment rather than a definitive answer. Take a look at this [article about StageVideo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSe9ecd9e6b89aefd2-68d5ef8f12cc8511f6c-7ffe.html). You can listen for VideoEvent.RENDER_STATE events on a Video object to get some info about how the video is being decoded and rendered. Note there are three VideoEvent classes, you want to use the `flash.events.VideoEvent` class and you can listen for this event if you play video with a `Video` object.

Comment: Is it possible to listen to that event using javascript? I saw only actionscript examples and I'm afraid that I don't know that language.

If actionscript is the only option, can I create an actionscript code and inject it to Youtube.com page in order to listen to the existing video? (I know how to inject the file, I just wonder if actionscript need to be included with the embedded file in order to listen to its events or it can be included separately)

Comment: No, you can only listen to those events in Actionscript. If you controlled the source (which I assume you don't, since you're using the youtube player), you could use the Actionscript ExternalInterface class to communicate w/Javascript and notify JS when such an event was dispatched.

Comment: bummer.... thx anyway :)